# Class object has no attribute tk?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am fairly new to python and with the help of tutorials I am trying to create a calculator but got stuck due to an error which I am unable to correct which occurs when I press a number button

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("Yuvi's CAl")
global char

class cal():

    def __init__(self):
        self.string= StringVar()
        root=Tk()
        root.title("Yuvi's CAl")
        self.string=StringVar
        enter=Entry(root,textvariable=self.string)
        enter.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6)
        values=["1","2","3","4","5","+","6","7","=","8","9","c"]
        row=1
        col=0
        i=0
        for txt in values:
            if i==3:
                row=3
                col=0
            if i==6:
                row=4
                col=0
            if i==9:
                row=5
                col=0

            if txt=="+":
                but=Button(root,text=txt)
                but.grid(row=row,column=col)
            elif txt=="=":
                but=Button(root,text=txt,command=lambda:self.equals)
                but.grid(row=row,column=col) 
            elif txt=="c":
                but=Button(root,text=txt,command=lambda:self.clr)
                but.grid(row=row,column=col)
            else:
                but=Button(root,text=txt,command=lambda txt=txt:self.add(txt))
                but.grid(row=row,column=col) 

            col+=1
            i+=1
    def add(self,char):
            meet=self.string.get(self)
            self.string.set((str(meet)) + (str(char)))


    def equals(self):
            result=eval(self.string.get())
            self.string.set(result)
    def clr(self):
            self.string.set("")

ent=cal()

root.mainloop()
```

and this being the error when I press a number button

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/yuvi/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/GUI/src/Misiio_calcuator.py", line 40, in <lambda>
    but=Button(root,text=txt,command=lambda txt=txt:self.add(txt))
  File "/home/yuvi/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/GUI/src/Misiio_calcuator.py", line 46, in add
    meet=self.string.get(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 339, in get
    value = self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name)
AttributeError: 'cal' object has no attribute '_tk'
```

Do rectify if any mistakes
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code first you should remove hiding your global vars within your `__init__` as it creates two windows and only running `mainloop` for one of them. In addition you overwrite `self.string` with the `StringVar` class object after first creating an instance of it. So your `__init__` could look like so

```
...
def __init__(self):
    self.string=StringVar()
    enter=Entry(root,textvariable=self.string)
    enter.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6)
    values=["1","2","3","4","5","+","6","7","=","8","9","c"]
    row=1
    col=0
    i=0
...
```

then in your `add` you don't have to pass `self` to `self.string.get`, that is it should look like

```
...
def add(self,char):
    meet=self.string.get()
    self.string.set((str(meet)) + (str(char)))
...
```

Those changes fixes your exception but I guess there are still other logical mistakes in the calculator, however that's not what the question is about and fixing them wouldn't help you learning python.